# STM32 communication

Tags: stm32, embedded, uart

I am using two stm32H7A3ZI-Q.
Both boards are used to generate data that is transmitted and received (IT) via UART to each other.

This data is used to as a variable to calculate a set of equations in both boards.
The data changes each cycle.

When printing the data via the serial comms into putty I get data for about 3 cycles then it turns to NANs.
I was wondering what could be causing this?

Key Updates.

1. I am using a jumper cables between the boards to send the data.
2. I am seeing nan's from the serial comms on putty.
3. I have grounded the grounds between the boards.
4. The image below is a section of what is getting printed [image]
5. This is the code i am using to transmit and receive data
   [image]

I have solve my problem. Like a said earlier think they are out of sync, Tx, and Rx. They were i used the function below to solve the problem.
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);

Comment: Bugs? Watchdog? Bad signal ground? Not nearly enough info to tell.

Comment: What information's do you need? I will update the questions about

Comment: There could be any number of causes. How are they connected? Have you verified the signals with a scope? Have you debugged both microcontrollers? Is the watchdog enabled?

Comment: I have them connected by a jumper cable. I connected the jumper from Rx to TX on the same board  and it. It seems to stop working when connecting Rx(Board 1) to TX(Board 2) and Rx(Board 2) to TX(Board 1)  of the other board.   I have not tested on a scope. I have debugged both microcontrollers. I am not sure what watchdog does. I will have a look at it

Comment: No ground then? You need one. Also, you really can't troubleshoot things like this without both an in-circuit debugger and an oscilloscope. Merely staring intently at the PCB won't solve anything...

Comment: I thought the issue is that the boards could be out of sync

Comment: Either communication is failing, or communication is working correctly and something else is failing. You'll need to use troubleshooting techniques to figure out what's going on. Try testing each part of your setup separately: test one board, then test the other board, then test communications between them. If the debug pins are available, then attach a debugger to get more information.

Comment: "I thought the issue is that the boards could be out of sync" What does that even mean? UART is asynchronous. Each part obviously needs to use the same baudrate, but you say that some correct data is getting through, so that's not it.

Comment: when using RX(board 1) to TX(board 2) it worked fine. it stop working when RX(board 1) to TX(board 2) and TX(board 1) to RX(board 2)

Comment: Connect the ground wire between them.

Comment: "_it turns to NANs_" ... does this mean you see `NAN` in the UART output?... if so, I'd imagine this is nothing to do with the UART, and entirely to do with a floating point algorithm somewhere else.

Comment: @Attie Unless NaN equals binary "all ones".

Comment: @Lundin I'm referring to the 3x ASCII characters... `NAN` doesn't have a meaning I can think of within the context of UARTs. (clarification please OP!)

Comment: I mean the output to the putty via the serial comms is NAN

Comment: You haven't told how boards are connected, what they communicate and how, and what prints out as a NAN where.

Comment: They are sending a double, the boards are connect by a jumper. I will add a picture of what is being printed

Comment: But when i connect tx to rx on the same board it is fine, it is when i connect to the other board

Comment: @CircuitFreak You're going to need to share a lot more info about what you're doing here... The fact that "_closing the loop_" makes it "_break_", suggests there's some sort of numeric feedback going on - I'd guess this isn't a hardware issue. Can you try simulating it on a PC?

Comment: I have an image of code that i am using to transmit the data.

Comment: What baud rate are you using and what is the clock source for each board?  Internal oscillators can be inaccurate enough to result in baud rate mismatches between boards.  Does it work better at a slower baud rate?

Comment: 1115200, thank you all for your help!

Comment: The code you posted has no relevance for the output posted. Where did those commas go? There's lots of fishy casts in that code. Or are you per chance posting the wrong code? Can you share more of the code in _text_ format (not pictures of code)?

Comment: "nan" (not a number) is a very specific floating-point value. With few exceptions, it can only arise from invalid math operations such as division by 0 followed by addition, square root of negative number etc. Check your math calculations.

Answer (score 4):

Transmitting `sizeof(txbuf)` number of bytes is almost certainly a bug. The "nan" etc garbage likely comes from sending uninitialized parts of the buffer way past the null terminator generated by `sprintf`.

Instead you should be transmitting `strlen(txbuf)` number of bytes. Or alternatively `strlen(txbuf)+1` if you wish to include a null terminator at the end of the UART data. (Since `sprintf` returns the number of bytes written, you could use that result as well.)

In addition there are lots of fishy casts and at least one of them is incorrect.

Comment: Since the sprintf() already returns the length of the string that was written to buffer, it's not very efficient to have an extra call to strlen() to go through the string again to find the length for the second time.

Comment: @Justme True, but since `sprintf` is present in the code in the first place, the OP already threw performance out the window...

Answer (score 2):

The `nan` output you see means "[*Not a Number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)" and can occur for a wide number of reasons when floating point numbers "*go wrong*". (`nan` can also be styalized as `NaN` or `NAN` depending on the libraries being used).

This isn't an error with the UART, but rather something to do with your algorithm and/or software.

Without a lot more detail about what you're doing and how, we can't possibly start to guess at what might be going wrong here, sorry.

This could be happening because you're writing past the end of a buffer (very possible given the snippet of code you've shared), or perhaps you're doing bad maths (e.g: `x/0.0` or `sqrt(-1)`).

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts data reception via interrupts, but immediately after starting the reception, even without receiving any data, you are trying to convert nothing that has been received into three floats.

So this is not a UART error. You are simply not converting any received data because you never wait for the data to be received.

Of course, impossible to say what your code does outside of those four lines of code.

Comment: Just FYI: it's `a` 'yoo-art', not `an` 'oo-art'. Same for USB, etc.

Comment: @brhans Thanks, I should have known that better but I don't think I've ever given much thought to that, but I'll make an effort to try. The languages where e.g. letter "u" is always a wovel and is always spelled/pronunciated identically regardless of the context are so much easier :)